# Hazelcast Fencedlock (Unsafe CP subsystem mode) vs ILock

Tags: hazelcast

Our team is in the process of upgrading the Hazelcast services from v 3.12 to v 5.3 and is evaluating the provided distributed locking feature.

Question is that will the Fencedlock (with Unsafe CP subsystem) provides the same locking features as ILock available in previously 3.x version?

Will the Fencedlock provide the same level of locking guarantee/mechanism/features as ILock. Is there anything need to be aware of when using Fencedlock with unsafe CP subsystem mode? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `ILock` was deprecated and removed since it was considered to have weak consistency.

https://docs.hazelcast.com/hazelcast/5.3/migrate/upgrading-from-imdg-3#removal-of-deprecated-concurrency-api-implementations

`FencedLock` will only provide strong consistency when CP subsystem are enabled. If it is running in unsafe mode strong consistency cannot be guaranteed.

From docs:

> Unsafe mode provides weaker consistency guarantees than the CP
> Subsystem. For example, when you increment an atomic long in unsafe
> mode, even though you may receive a success response, operations such
> as increments can be lost if a member fails.
>
> As a result, unsafe mode is not recommended for use cases that require
> strong consistency. Instead, this mode is suitable only for
> development or testing.